# What do the numbers in the valgrind's outputs mean?

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

I have this output from valgrind:

```
==4836== 10,232 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==4836==    at 0x4C2779D: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4836==    by 0x401865: thrt() (main.cpp:221)
==4836==    by 0x4048B1: main (tester.cpp:35)
```

1. what does `==4836==`  mean?
2. what does `0x4C2779D` mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your first question: that number represents the process ID.

Look at the [official source](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.interpret).

From this same source, we can see the answer to your second question:

> The code addresses (eg. 0x804838F) are usually unimportant, but occasionally crucial for tracking down weirder bugs.

Comment: `==XXXX==` is also the PID of the running process.  But that's in the documentation, too.